# Query Showing Multiple Iterations of Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I created an SSIS package that takes in a CSV file and imports it into a table called "OPEX_Spend" but when I run a query it queries multiple iterations of the table. The table should show 336 rows but instead there are 1002. Any ideas why it's doing that? Here is how everything is set up:

**Data flow:**

1. Flat File Source
2. Lookup Transformation
3. OLE DB Destination

**Here are how the tables are set up:**

```
CREATE TABLE OPEX_Accounts (
Account_ID int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
OPEX_Name varchar(50),
GL_Account varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE OPEX_Spend (
Actuals_ID int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Account_ID int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_OPEXID 
FOREIGN KEY (Account_ID) REFERENCES OPEX_Accounts (Account_ID),
Actuals_Date varchar(50),
Transaction_Text varchar (50),
Actuals_Amount numeric
)
```

Comment: `OPEX_account` rows number is OK ? Maybe you have triggers on the table?

Comment: Yes, the opex_account table is fine.What do you mean by triggers?

Comment: Triggers are instructions executed on insert / update / delete

Comment: Are they within the data flow?